# jQuery Cycle Plugin For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been stumped trying to figure out how to integrate a simple for loop to work with the jQuery Cycle plugin. In my basic example I am trying to create 15 cycle functions using jquery `.hover()` and `.cycle()`.

```
for(i=1;i<15;i++){
    $(".t"+ i).hover(function() {
        $('.projectTitle').cycle(i);
    });
}
```

If I create 15 separate functions(per below) the script runs fine but I am in need of simplifying my code.

```
$('.t1').hover(function() {
    $('.projectTitle').cycle(1);
});
$('.t2').hover(function() {
    $('.projectTitle').cycle(2);
});
$('.t3').hover(function() {
    $('.projectTitle').cycle(3);
});
$('.t4').hover(function() {
    $('.projectTitle').cycle(4);
});
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it just doesn't work like you have it in your first example? Any errors?

Comment: @Jack The problem is that after the loop finishes, `i` is equal to fifteen and that will be the value used by each anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can circumvent the whole closure issue by storing `i` as a data attribute in the DOM element itself:

```
for (var i=1; i<=15; i++) {
    $('.t'+i).data("inc",i).hover(function() { 
        $('.projectTitle').cycle( $(this).data("inc") ); 
    });
}
```

(Incidentally, you should probably replace all those classes with IDs, for performance.)

The "right" way to do this is with a JavaScript closure, which I'm no expert in, but I think should look like this:

```
for (var i=1; i<=15; i++) {
    $('.t'+i).hover(
        (function() { 
            var a = i;
            return function() { $('.projectTitle').cycle( a ); }
        })()
    );
}
```

Comment: Genius Answer!!! Is there a noticeable difference in IDs running faster? I have always preferred to use classes in the case that I may want to reuse a class on multiple elements. In this case I may have two elements that use .t1 but most likely would only have one element that uses .projectTitle in which case I should make this an ID.

Comment: How noticable it is depends on how often you do it. For fifteen elements, you won't notice much difference, but it's Good Practice to use IDs whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the correct order in the DOM you can use the index provided by jQuery's each and give them all the same class:

```
$('.t').each(function(index) { 
    $(this).mouseover( function() { // Use mouseover instead of hover, otherwise your function will be run on mouseover AND mouseout
        $('.projectTitle').cycle( index ); 
    }
});
```